# Remove header and footer in android studio webview

Tags: java, android, wordpress

I've already searched all over for a solution but couldn't get any answer. I need to build a webview app for my WordPress site and I need a practical method that would help display contents without the header and footer. I'm a newbie at Android studio. This is what I tried

```
WebView custom;
String removeHeader1 = "javascript:document.getElementById('site-description').remove();";
String removeHeader2 = "javascript:document.getElementById('st').remove();";
String removeHeader3 = "javascript:document.getElementById('search').remove();";
String removeHeader4 = "javascript:document.getElementById('search-submit').remove();";

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_town);
    custom = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings settings = custom.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    custom.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    custom.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    custom.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    custom.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    custom.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    custom.setFocusable(true);
    custom.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    custom.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    custom.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    custom.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    custom.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    custom.evaluateJavascript(removeHeader1 , null);
    custom.evaluateJavascript(removeHeader2 , null);
    custom.evaluateJavascript(removeHeader3 , null);
    custom.evaluateJavascript(removeHeader4 , null);
    custom.loadUrl("https://linknigeria.com.ng/students");
    custom.setWebViewClient(new CustomTown.myWebClient());
    custom.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        //The undocumented magic method override
        //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            CustomTown.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            CustomTown.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        //For Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            CustomTown.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), CustomTown.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

    });


    setContentView(custom);


}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    //ProgressDialog
    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        pd= new ProgressDialog(CustomTown.this);
        pd.setTitle("#BeFree");
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }





    //Alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        try {
            custom.stopLoading();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (custom.canGoBack()) {
            custom.goBack();
        }

        custom.loadUrl("about:blank");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomTown.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
        super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }






    @Override
    public boolean
    shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished
            (WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        pd.dismiss();
    }




}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (custom.canGoBack()) {
                    custom.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

//flipscreen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

The footer.php file can be found here [enter link description here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/2bbc5516)
The header.php file can be found here [enter link description here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/995efca7)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make changes to the webpage, webView needs to be enabled to execute Javascript.
This is done by the API `setJavaScriptEnabled()` which accepts a boolean parameter. **True** for enabling javascript execution.

To remove the header and footer, the ids of the same are needed. That can be obtained by checking the JS file of the webpage.

Say the id for header is `page_header`and that of footer is `page_footer`.

Assign a string variable to the script `javascript:document.getElementById('page_header').remove();`

This will find the id in that web page and remove it due to the `remove()` method.

We then just need to execute the above script.
`webview.evaluateJavaScript()` helps us do that. The parameters required are the script and callback. The callback can be null if none is needed.

Hence to remove the header,

```
`String removeHeader = "javascript:document.getElementById('page_header').remove();";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript(script, callback);

} else
    webView.loadUrl(script, null);`
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by execute "evaluateJavascript()" sorry I'm a newbie. Can I get an explanatory sample?

Comment: @Abiola The method `evaluateJavascript()` is an API provided by the webview class. Have updated the answer

Comment: it says only kitkat allowed...sadly...it can only work for KitKat +

Comment: @Abiola For versions below KitKat webview.loadurl(script, null) should work. Add an if-else condition to check the SDK version

Comment: i don't understand kindly update the answer so it could be clearer... I have webview.loadurl("example.com") already, I don't understand this webview.loadurl(script, null) and where should I add the if?

Comment: @Abiola Try first executing the webView.loadUrl(script,null) and then the url. Have edited the answer

Comment: Hi, I tried your method but the header in my WordPress site still shows in the webview when I load it. I took the ids from the template file...header.php is this correct?

Comment: I would update the question with my changes and maybe you can correct it and i would also upload the footer and header files in the template i purchased

Comment: @Abiola I will have a look

Comment: great..i'd be waiting for your response

Comment: Having some issue.. Will try n figure it out

Comment: any solutions yet?